# How to add PATH environment variable to the HomeBrew Profiles

Tags: terminal, mac, homebrew

As said in the title, I usually use Installer to install [`Golang`](https://go.dev/). I try to install the tool [`buf`](https://buf.build/) in brew. Its depend to [`Golang`](https://go.dev/). Obviously，brew install the [`Golang`](https://go.dev/) again. That is same to i install some need to `OpenJDK` Tools.

I want to know is how add the **PATH variable** to the brew config. Make it to know [`Golang`](https://go.dev/) or other dependency is correct installed. Just like add **Path Environment Variable** to `.zshrc`. Brew also find the [`Golang`](https://go.dev/) Path. Any answers would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Homebrew builds assuming it finds homebrew forms of go etc. If you want to use things that depend on your own go then you need to install your own new thing and not via homebrew. Basically once you have non package managed things then you have left the package manager's world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr You don't need build dependencies to install packages [from a Bottle](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles).

I didn't require Go installed, Homebrew or otherwise, to install buf.

---

Let's start with `brew info buf` to see what we're working with

```
$ brew info buf
==> buf: stable 1.15.1 (bottled), HEAD
…
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘
==> Options
…
==> Analytics
…
```

The two key pieces of information here are

> ```
> ==> buf: stable 1.15.1 (bottled), HEAD
> ```

> ```
> Build: go ✘
> ```

This tells us:

- buf is available in a bottle

  > Bottles are simple gzipped tarballs of compiled binaries.

  <sup>https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles</sup>
- building `buf` depends on `go`, which is not installed with Brew (hence `✘`).

This means you don't need to install `go` just to install `buf` from a bottle, as I was successfully able to do:

```
$ brew install buf
==> Fetching buf
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/buf/manifests/1.17.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/buf/blobs/sha256:b190b169d11d6acb1d81d9da47c1369074ee50deee237e4c544ca79731c78b6a
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:b190b169d11d6acb1d81d9da47c1369074ee50deee237e4c544ca79731c78b6a?se=2023-04
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring buf--1.17.0.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
fish completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/buf/1.17.0: 86 files, 56.0MB

$ buf -h
The Buf CLI

A tool for working with Protocol Buffers and managing resources on the Buf Schema Registry (BSR)

…
```

If your install is building from source, see ‘Bottles will not be used if:’ section of https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles.

---

If you want to install a package with Homebrew and you know you don't need its help in installing dependencies, you can always use `--ignore-dependencies` with `brew install`.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer!!!!!  It's useful to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/buf.rb) used to install `buf` has a dependency to the Homebrew `go` package, this will trigger the installation of Homebrew's `go` if it isn't installed via Homebrew yet.

```
...
  depends_on "go" => :build

  def install
    %w[buf protoc-gen-buf-breaking protoc-gen-buf-lint].each do |name|
      system "go", "build", *std_go_args(ldflags: "-s -w", output: bin/name), "./cmd/#{name}"
    end
```

To avoid a duplicated `go` installation, you can either install `go` via Homebrew only, or roll your own formula for `buf` which doesn't depend on the `go` package.

Comment: Thanks your answers. This gave me a new idea. Thanks for your help again!